# Angular 7 Upgrade "export 'STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS' was not found in '@angular/cdk/stepper'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I upgraded my angular project to 7.1.4.
after upgrade 'STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS' was not found in '@angular/cdk/stepper'

there is my package.json

tried to remove all packages from  node_modules and run npm install

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
"@angular/common": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/forms": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/http": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.4",
"@angular/router": "^7.1.4",
"angular-progress-bar": "^1.0.9",
"core-js": "^2.5.7",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.3",
"material-icons": "^0.2.3",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
"popper.js": "^1.14.4",
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
```

},

how do i fixed that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your **@angular/Material** and **@angular/cdk** packages are at the same version level.

This happened to me this morning, and eventually I saw that my @angular/Material package was at 7.2.0 while my @angular/cdk was at 7.1.4.   I updated @angular/cdk to 7.2.0 and the warning went away.

Comment: Great! fixed my problem